# Adding Colspan to mat-table header

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I want to add a colspan to a mat-table mat-header.

Current Link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bklajw-mwqqvl?file=app/table-basic-example.html

I couldn't find any other example where one mat-header-cell is used with multiple mat-cell

Desired output: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have to use the same array for the columns and the header columns. Use two different arrays :)

```js
displayedHeaderColumns: string[] = ['name', 'weight'];
displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
```

Now in your template you can use `displayedHeaderColumns` for the `headerColumns`

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
  <th mat-header-cell colspan="2" *matHeaderCellDef>Properties</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.weight}}</td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.symbol}}</td>
</ng-container>

<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedHeaderColumns"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
```

Notice the `colspan` attribute on the **weight** column.

Here you can see the running [different header columns for a matTable example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bklajw-znrvaj).

Comment: you has a type error in your stackblitz -you use in your ts "displazedHeaderColumns" and hould be "displayedHeaderColumns" (see that the "z" should be a "y")